# how do i get local machine ip address ipv4 address when ever user visit on my website?

Tags: php, ip, ipv4

how do I get local machine IP address ipv4 address whenever user visit my website on the server?

```
function getLocalIP(){
exec("ipconfig /all", $output);
    foreach($output as $line){
        if (preg_match("/(.*)IPv4 Address(.*)/", $line)){
            $ip = $line;
            $ip = str_replace("IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . :","",$ip);
            $ip = str_replace("(Preferred)","",$ip);
        }
    }
return $ip;
}

echo $ip = getLocalIP(); //This will return: 192.168.x.x (Your Local IP)
```

The problem code is not showing anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the client IP address in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php)

Comment: @JitendraSoftgrid my code is different than the other question please and then give your answer

Comment: $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; for client's IP

Comment: So, if your question is different, please clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

check `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`, I gues client ip is there

Comment: i have try it but it is showing real ip not local system ip

Comment: yes, local machine IP address on the server like 192.168.100.10